# Safe query in linq-sql?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have the following query:

```
   dat =
from s in dat
orderby s.Schedule.Employee.EmployeName ascending
select s;
```

The problem is `Schedule` or `Employee` might be `null`, in those cases, it should just either show those first or last, I dont care.

Is there a way to do this? Currently it crashes when it is `null`.

Used to  sort a grid view:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   KezberProjectManager.Cases.<gvCases_Sorting>b__8(Case s) in C:\Users\jlarouche\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\KezberProjectManager\KezberProjectManager\Cases.aspx.cs:103
   System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`2.ComputeKeys(TElement[] elements, Int32 count) +88
   System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`1.Sort(TElement[] elements, Int32 count) +21
   System.Linq.<GetEnumerator>d__0.MoveNext() +178
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding) +1698
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +67
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +14
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data) +123
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +33
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +138
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +30
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +4
   KezberProjectManager.Cases.gvCases_Sorting(Object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e) in C:\Users\jlarouche\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\KezberProjectManager\KezberProjectManager\Cases.aspx.cs:138
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnSorting(GridViewSortEventArgs e) +122
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleSort(String sortExpression, SortDirection sortDirection) +65
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleSort(String sortExpression) +78
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup) +497
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +205
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +9642898
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

Comment: Just to be clear, this query crashes when it is `null`?  So, that being said, what are you trying to accomplish with this code snippet?  Also, what is the `exception.Message` of what you are catching?

Comment: This doesn't look like a LINQ-to-SQL stacktrace to me. Are you sure `dat` is backed by a LINQ-to-SQL context?

Answer (score 4):

You need to check for `null` before accessing the properties:

```
var x = from s in dat
        let s = s.Schedule
        let e = s == null ? null : s.Employee
        orderby e == null ? null : e.EmployeeName ascending
        select s;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
dat =
    from s in dat
    orderby 
       s.Schedule == null ? "" : 
       s.Schedule.Employee == null ? "" : 
       s.Schedule.Employee.EmployeName ascending
    select s;
```

Answer (score 0):

So why don't you use an if condition to check for nulls in those objects and handle it there? The big question here I guess is should they ever be null? It sounds like this code should be prevented from running further back in the application if so.

Answer (score -1):

You have the `FirstOrDefault()`, `LastOrDefault()` and `DefaultIfEmpty()` methods to address this situation.

Comment: I don't think there's any clean way to use those methods to accomplish ordering in the way the OP needs here.

Comment: I don't think that is the correct solution, his code throws because one of the properties sorted on is `null`, not because he has no elements in the sequence.